# Creating a Dictionary-like storage to keep metainformation about various Board states

Tags: c#, dictionary

Say I have a data storage class like so:

```
public class Board
{
    private T[,] board = new T[3,3];

    public T this[int i, int j]
    get
    {
        return board[i,j];
    }
    set
    {
        board[i,j] = value;
    }
}
```

and then a class which stores a Board and some additional data alongside it:

```
public class BoardHelper
{
    public Board board { get; private set; }
    public bool foo;
    public bool bar;
}
```

is it possible to create some sort of custom `List<BoardHelper>` or `Dict<BoardHelper>` style class that I can index by `Board`, so that I can do something like

```
MyList<BoardHelper> boardList
Board board = someBoard;
if (boardList[board].foo)
    // logic goes here
```

?

EDIT: Thought of another way of phrasing the question.

I have a Board class, which stores some data.
I also want to be able to store some metadata about each Board, things that are known about particular configurations.

I want to be able to pass an arbitrary Board as defined by the values in the 3x3 array, and return the metadata that is known about that particular set of values.

Comment: it's very unclear what you're asking, if you already have the board, why access it through a dictionary where the board is the key? maybe the example doesn't reflect your intention?

Comment: Forget it, just read wrong your example, instead of `List<BoardHelper>` create a `Dictionary<Board, BoardHelper>`

Comment: `boardList[someBoard].foo` should return the `foo` attribute of the `BoardHelper` instance with a `board` attribute of `someBoard`. Does that make sense?

Comment: I would start with implementing the IEquatable interface in your Board class

Comment: @AshwinNair If he wants distinct `Board` objects (i.e. those with different references) to be distinct in a dictionary then the default `GetHashCode()` and `Object.Equals()` should be fine.

Comment: @MatthewWatson ....Good point....Although, I doubt that's what the OP has in mind.

Comment: If you want to be able to sort a class use IComparible which also will test for equal.  So if you want to be able to get items from a dictionary where the key is multiple object the IComparible is needed.  You also need to impliment the method CompareTo().

Comment: if you want meta data then there is a high chance that there will be multiple entries per key, in which case you need a lookup not a dictionary

Comment: I know what I'm planning to store already. There will only be a few hundred values that a Board instance can take, and each one will have unique metadata stored against it.

This is for a first foray into machine learning - I plan to write a program that can learn to play noughts and crosses. So against each board configuration I want to store whether it's a winning game state, and all the board-states that can be produced from the current state in one move.

Comment: I allowed myself to improve the title a bit to match the question a little closer. Please feel free to reedit/improve that further if you think the current wording doesnt feel right!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding:

> (..) let you take an arbitrary Board as defined by the values in the 3x3 array, and look up the metadata associated with that set of values?

You don't need a special dictionary, what you need is a smart way to tell the dictionary what does it mean to "Look up a board".

For you, of a BoardA is (o,o,- / x,-,o / x,x,-) and BoardB is (o,o,- / x,-,o / x,x,-) then it's the same, and you want the dictionary to fetch the same data for both of them. However, if you just use it directly:

```
Dictionary<Board, foo>
```

then the dictionary will by default compare object-hashes and object-equality, and most probably BoardA instance will be understood as different than BoardB instance.

You can solve that through **many** ways.

The simpliest way is to change the **key**. Since you actually want to match the metadata by the **board contents**, then you can do so. But just don't take the inner-array as in

```
Dictionary<int[,], foo>
```

because arrays are also compared by default by object-equality, so array from boardA wont == array from boardB (unless you add more tricks, later on it).

However, one thing that's really simple and plain to use as keys are strings. Encode your board as a string and use it as key.

```
BOARD       intermediate concept         BOARD-CODE
oo-
x-o    =>   (o,o,- / x,-,o / x,x,-)  => "oo-x-oxx-"
xx-
```

then

```
Dictionary<string, foo>
myDict[ boardA.boardcode ]
myDict[ boardB.boardcode ]
```

will get you the same metadata object, depending solely on the board-code, that is, on the board contents.

What you need to make sure that the 'code' is built in such way that it is actually unique for each board setup.

Finally, it does not need to be a string as you probably already see. Given some determination (or memory constraints!) you can pack that as a bit-stream into integers, etc. In your case, each board cell is O/X/- so 3-state, needs a little less than 2 bits. Packing as stream takes up, say, 1 byte per cell. Wasteful, but in your case it's allowable, as you dont have that many states to cover.

Now, rewind.

Packing as string, adding ".boardcode" property. That can be done in a few minutes. But that's indexing the dictionary by strings. You can feel that's ugly. You can also don't like keeping the "boardcode" in the board.

That's why Dictionary allows you to provide a IComparer, so you can actually **tell the dictionary** what does it mean that "boards are the same", without hacks.

Write a IComparer that will calculate GetHashCode and Equals that will investigate the board's contents, and pass such comparer to the

```
Dictionary<Board, foo>
```

and the comparer will make sure that the dictionary hits the same items both for BoardA and BoardB. It takes a little more time to write, it can also be actually **slower** than the string-based approach (because if you write the comparer naiively, it will be redoing make many compare-loops over the arrays constantly), but .. well, tradeoffs everywhere.

afterthought:

One important thing you probably will want to take from all that wall of text from me is the idea of "fingerprinting" the board and keying over that.

The string-based example I gave you was to pack all the board's state into a string (some "key" that describes the contents). For more complex games, it may be not feasible to pack everything and, also, to generate metadata for all possible board or game states.

Then, you need to invent a way to create "keys" that describe only some important aspects of the game state. I.e. instead of:

```
o??                       ??o
???    -> o????????       ???   ->  ??o??????
???                       ???

x??
???    -> x????????      ...and so on
???
```

you may notice that that's actually the same symmetric characteristic that could be encoded as:

```
(any board with O in corner)         ->     M?????????
(any board with X in corner)         ->     N?????????
(any board with nothing in corner)   ->     O?????????
```

that's completely useless and artificial example, but such "packing" can not only save great number of states, but also allows you to see that matching states can be ether full (as in my original examples) or can be built around **partial** matches or hit rules (item in a corner? empty center? two items and a free cell in the same line? ..)

so.. probably a simple container like a dictionary<>+comparer will not be enough in some future versions of your experiments, all that depends on what encoding and matching you come up with!

Comment: That looks really helpful, thanks! Some poking around through the C# docs guided by this leads me to believe that what I want is actually the EqualityComparer<T> class - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132123(v=vs.110).aspx

Is this right?

Comment: Yes, you're right. Then you will be able to use [this constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.100).aspx) to create a smarter-dictionary that will use the comparer to match your key-objects. Please be careful with GetHashCode, it is very important that this method is allowed to form false-positives (which then are resolved with full-blown Equals that you also need to write), but in turn it **must not create false-negatives**.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the board helper instance with the same `board` as your variable, you can use `Where` to filter:

```
BoardHelper helper = boardList.Where(bh => bh.board == board).SingleOrDefault();
```

From there, you can check its `foo` property:

```
if (helper.foo)
{ }
```

Comment: i would normally use firstordefault as single will error on multiple matches

Comment: That was intentional. In the worst case, you get unexpected results when there are more helpers with the same `board`. @MikeT

Comment: @AshwinNair No. See the code from OP. He misspelled the property names.

Comment: @PatrickHofman actually he's referring to the fact you used assignment not compare equality

Comment: I meant to correct the single equal actually. Sorry I wasn't clear.

Comment: @AshwinNair Oh, yes. True. Thanks.

Comment: Tried to edit your post, but stack overflow needs me to make an edit of at least 6 characters when all I want to add is "=". It'd be interesting to know why they have the 6 char minimum. :)

Comment: To prevent single character edits to flood the suggested edit review queue @AshwinNair

Answer (score 0):

If you want just a way to acces it just use a `Dictionary<Board, BoardHelper>`, else if you want a custom class you must create a class which implements `IDictionary<Boad, BoardHelper>`

Answer (score 0):

Just focusing on OP's last edit,

If you have the board, and metadata is unique to each Board, make it a property

```
public class Board
{
  public BoardConfig metadata {get;set;}

  private T[,] board = new T[3,3];

  public T this[int i, int j]
  get
  {
    return board[i,j];
  }
  set
  {
    board[i,j] = value;
  }
}
```

Comment: And that will let you take an arbitrary Board as defined by the values in the 3x3 array, and look up the metadata associated with that set of values?

Comment: @TamCoton: no, it will not. This code from Ashwin assumes that each Board keeps its own metadata. It's not what you stated now.

Comment: @TamCoton, when you say "Board as defined by the values in the 3x3 array", I'm imagining a method that will accept a 3x3 array and return the first board in a board list that matches. You could use the metadata of that board

Answer (score 0):

If you take

```
List<BoardHelper> myBhList = ....;
```

then there's a linq extension method ToDictionary that you can use.
So just do

```
var theDictIWasLookingFor = myBhList.ToDictionary(x=>x.board, x=> x);
```

Now you have the dictionary indexes by board returning the whole BoardHelper objects.

Answer (score 0):

I'm making this far too complicated, aren't I? I don't think I actually need to make a custom dict or anything, this should work, shouldn't it?

```
public class Board
{
    private T[,] board = new T[3,3];

    public T this[int i, int j]
    get
    {
        return board[i,j];
    }
    set
    {
        board[i,j] = value;
    }
}

public class Metadata
{
    bool foo;
    bool bar;
    var any other data I fancy storing;
}

Dict<Board,Metadata> boardList = new Dict<Board,Metadata>();
```

There's no actual need to store the board in the metadata, that's the Dict's job.

Comment: in short, yes, that's a good direction, but please read my answer too. By default, Dictionary compares keys by normal, C#/CLR/.Net object equality, including prefiltering by hashcodes. This means that if you create `a = new Board(); b = new Board()` and fill A/B with the same **contents** and then look it up in the dictioanry, you will get **different matches** because **object A is not the same as object B** simply because that's two diffferent objects with different hashcodes. You need a Comparer, or GetHashCode/Equals override, or other tricks. Or need to ensure that each Board is unique.